Nav2 - Conceptual: Global and local planner pipeline without Z Rotation
I'm working on a robot that can move along x/y axis (mecanum wheels) but is constrained: It cannot, at any time, rotate around it's z axis.
I'm new to nav2, but figured most of the setup out, e.g. servers, global planner, controllers (local planners). I've written a node that requests to plan a path, which is successful. I can see that path in RViz.
When I execute that path, I see that /cmd_vel is containing angular velocity in/ around z. Which is what I have expected, because I didn't told MPPI that it cannot move around z.
So, to my question:
What is the correct approach for my robot? Is there any controller plugin that can be configured as 'no z rotation, don't care about the orientation in the pose'?
Is it necessary to use a global planner plugin that produces poses only with RPY=0,0,0 w.r.t the odom frame? I've already used the straight line global planning plugin from nav2-tutorials. In that plugin, the computed poses have always a fixed pose. It didn't solve my problem so I think it has something to do with the local planner.
Thanks alot guys!
P.s.: This means, that any goal I want to set is independent of the pose. For my usecase, a point would be sufficient instead.

That's definitely a unique use-case and it should be possible, but I can't give you the 'this is what you need to do' off of hand. You could make a Pure Pursuit-like controller that finds the path carrot and rather than finding the angular velocity to follow it, you simply use its angle relative to the base to decide which contributions of X & Y is needed to follow that angle at your desired total velocity.
You could also modify MPPI's critics or DWB's trajectory generator to score or generate candidates (respectively) based on X & Y only ignoring orientation -- if you want more dynamic capable behavior. If you need path-following-only, then a carrot-follower would likely be the most expedient and reliable solution (likely with some caveats).
If you'd like some professional help with this, feel free to ping me (email's on my github https://github.com/SteveMacenski & website). This seems pretty attainable, even if I don't have the exact solution off hand I can say will definitely be the solution. But, I think this should be something you can do yourself if you roll up your sleeves!

Thanks for your quick answer. I'll be working on that next week again, will look into the critics thing as well as  writing my own controller plugin.
